# Nodejs REST API Sending large JSON chunk by chunk

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm trying to send large JSON to client but it fails (out of memory).

Can I send that JSON chunk by chunk?

Comment: Yes. Read about [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)

Comment: While streams would probably prevent an out of memory exception, perhaps you should explore if you need to send that much data to the client at all. That has to be in the realm of at least 100s of MBs and many clients (e.g. phones, tablets, etc.) would likely crash upon receiving and parsing that much data.

Comment: Exactly, problem is my boss needs all data from json, I explained that to him but still...